# SanDisk 1TB Portable SSD not recognized as disk when connected directly USB-C to USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, ssd, external-disk

Hi I recently purchased [a SanDisk 1TB Portable SSD](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16820173551?Description=sandisk&cm_re=sandisk-_-20-173-551-_-Product&quicklink=true). The SSD does not show up as a disk in either the Finder (with External Disks checked) or the Disk Utility (with show all devices selected).

I have [a USB C Hub, Type C Hub, Amkle 6-in-1 Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07439QJ6Q) which, has both USB-A and USB-C ports so I was able to test the following:

1. USB-C to MacBook Air 3.1 USB-C Port
2. USB-C to USB-C Amkle Port
3. USB-C to USB-A Amkle Port

Out of the three possible configurations, only USB-C to USB-A via the Amkle USB Hub works. USB-C to USB-C does not work through the hub or the Mac. The following is a screenshot of the System Report when plugged USB-C to USB-A (working) through the hub.
[image]

The following is a screenshot of the System Report plugged USB-C to USB-C (directly to MacBook).
[image]

Is there anything I can do to get USB-C direct to the MB USB-C port working? Note that I have tried a variety of USB-C cables that I have around.

Comment: Try a different USB-C to USB-C cable. If your Mac can see a USB hub and device (using a C to A converter), the port works.  The common denominator of 1 & 2 is the USB-C cable from the drive.  In #3, you aren’t using that cable.

Comment: @Allan I have tried several USB-C to USB-C cables "Note that I have tried a variety of USB-C cables that I have around." Are there any sanity checks I can do to verify the cables should be working?

Comment: Do they work with other devices?

Comment: @Allan I do not have another device to test with

Comment: I'm starting to think that it may be the case that USB-C cables I have may not support USB 3 data transfers. I'm considering buying a Thunderbolt 3 cable to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Is it possible those USB-C cables are “charge only?”  Get a [quality USB-C cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378574/119271).  If it has the USB-C logo, it must support data x-fer.

Comment: I am ordering this cable to test, will report back once it's arrived and tested https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4H2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-cable-08-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well turns out none of the USB-C cables I owned supported the spec required to plug in this drive. I bought [this cable from Apple](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4H2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-cable-08-m) which did the trick, but any cable that supports USB 3 data transfer would likely do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **USB C port** on the hub **only for charging**. The product page saying the USB C charging port; (Support 5V/3A charging).

If you just want to use your SSD with the USB C cable, I recommend a USB C to USB C Data Hub.
Such as [Satchi 4-PORT USB-C Hub](https://satechi.net/products/4-port-usb-c-hub). And make sure connecting the hub and the SSD with USB 3.1 Gen 2(or later version) cable.

Hope this help!